# Despliegue de resultados en java

Tags: java

Realizé un programa que me permite ingresar cualquier número con un límite que el usuario establece, y así desplegar los que son pares y los impares, pero cuando lo hago, tengo una coma demás en la derecha.

Los números pares son:

2, 4,

Los números impares son:

3, 5,

¿Cómo puedo corregir eso y quitar la coma extra del final?

```
String pares = "";
String impares = "";
int li, num;
System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de nuemros a evaluar: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
li = sc.nextInt();       

for (int i = 1; i <= li; i++) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i);
    num = sc.nextInt();
    if (num % 2 == 0) {
        pares += num + ", ";
    } else {
        impares += num + ", ";
    }
}
System.out.println("Los numeros pares son:" );
    System.out.print(pares);

System.out.println("\nLos numeros inpares pares son: ");
System.out.println(impares);
```

Comment: una solución sencilla es concatenar la coma sí y sólo sí `i<li`

Comment: Esa opción sólo quitaría la última coma de una de las 2 cadenas de texto, no de las 2.

Answer (score 2):

Un enfoque diferente. En lugar de ir creando la lista de resultados "pares" e "impares" sobre una cadena, guardarlos en cambio en un Array. Esto parece más natural, pues así tienes los números por separado (por si quisieras luego operar con ellos, por ejemplo sumar todos los pares) y no una representación de los mismos todos juntos en una cadena.

Además, si `pares` o `impares` son Arrays, puedes al final simplemente imprimirlos con `System.out.println(pares)` para obtener una representación automáticamente creada por Java que tendría este aspecto: `[2, 4]`.

Si los corchetes te molestan, puedes convertir el array en string y luego quitarlos, quedándote con la subcadena que va del carácter 1 al penúltimo.

Esta solución se implementaría por tanto así:

```java
  ArrayList<Integer> pares = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<Integer> impares = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  int li, num;
  String repr;

  System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de nuemros a evaluar: ");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  li = sc.nextInt();       

  for (int i = 1; i <= li; i++) {
      System.out.println("Ingrese su numero #" + i);
      num = sc.nextInt();
      if (num % 2 == 0) {
          pares.add(num);
      } else {
          impares.add(num);
      }
  }
  System.out.println("Los numeros pares son:" );
  repr = pares.toString();
  System.out.println(repr.substring(1, repr.length()-1));

  System.out.println("\nLos numeros inpares pares son: ");
  repr = impares.toString();
  System.out.println(repr.substring(1, repr.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Añade la coma *antes* del número

```
 pares += ", " + num;
```

pero no antes del primer número

```
 if (pares.isEmpty()) {
    pares += num;
 } else {
    pares += ", " + num;
 }
```

O, usando el operador condicional para hacerlo en una línea

```
 pares += (pares.isEmpty() ? "" : ", ") + num;
```

Answer (score 1):

Otro enfoque diferente, usando [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) de java 8. Te da la ventaja de que no tienes que cambiar casi nada de tu código. Cambia la declaración de `pares` e `impares` a:

```
StringJoiner pares = new StringJoiner(",");       // "," es el delimitador que StringJoiner
StringJoiner impares =  new StringJoiner(",");    // necesita para juntar las String
```

Y la adición a:

```
if (num % 2 == 0) {
    pares.add(String.valueOf(i));
} else {
    impares.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es sencillo, simplemente hay que quitar la coma detrás de cada una de las cadenas.

Al no saber los números que van a introducir, no lo podemos hacer dentro del bucle donde se van pidiendo los números, hay que hacerlo después de haber recogido todos los valores.

Para hacer esto, vamos a utilizar el método `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

Este método te devuelve una cadena de texto "recortada" desde el índice inicial hasta el índice final.

Como solo queremos quitar el último carácter, tenemos que recortar la cadena desde la posición 0 hasta la última -1 con lo cual, tendríamos que hacerlo así:

```
pares = pares.substring(0, pares.length()-2);
impares = impares.substring(0, impares.length()-2);
```

Comment: Sí, tu planteamiento está bien, pero ten en cuenta que el usuario está añadiendo la cadena de texto `", "`. Si te fijas hay un espacio al lado de la coma que también contaría como carácter, así que sería `pares.length() - 2`

Comment: cierto, arreglado.

Comment: Yo no usaría eso, usa un replace(",", ""), el substring funciona, pero no es seguro aunque conozcas la longitud (Por si hay que dar mantenimiento a una aplicación y otra persona cambia longitud o algo).

Comment: mmm... no veo cuando puede fallar. Si usas replace (como has puesto), sólo quitarías los espacios, no veo como lo puedes solucionar así.

Comment: no quito los espacios, quito las ","

Comment: Perdona, me había colado al leer la respuesta. Así si quitamos las comas, pero la salida por pantalla quedaría mejor poniendo comas en todos sitios menos al final. Si lo que quiere es quitar todas las comas sería más sencillo no ponerlas al concatenar los números.